# Find average by ignore blank cells, but consider cells has #N/A with 100% value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find average of 3 cells, but some of the cells are empty. I need empty cells to be excluded from the average.

There are few cells with #N/A error message. These cells need to be considered as 100% value.

This is the closest I have come so far.

```
=Averageif(C8:E8,">=0")

=Sumif(C8:e8,"<>#N/A")
```

Comment: aggregate still gives me a #DIV/O! error

Comment: then please show your data as you can see it is not doing that below.

Comment: If you have "numbers" in at least one cell then your "numbers are text that look like numbers(numbers stored as text).  If they are text then the average will ignore them.

Comment: @Laura, What do mean by consider 100% for #NA cells, are you want to ignore cells have ERROR messages?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2013 or later, you can use the `IFNA` function:

```
=SUM(IFNA(A1:C1,1))/COUNTA(A1:C1)
```

`COUNTA` will also count the `#N/A` cell

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE

```
=AGGREGATE(1,7,A1:C1)
```

The `1` is for Average and `7` tells it to ignore errors.

[image]

Comment: Your formula ignores the `#N/A`  I believe he wanted to value it as a `1`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Maybe, but the formula `Sumif(C8:e8,"<>#N/A")` that the op shared would contradict that.

Comment: I missed that.  Sometimes hard to know what someone wants.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution I could find is this:

`=(AGGREGATE(9,6,C4:E4)+COUNTIF(C4:E4,NA()))/COUNTIF(C4:E4,"<>")`

where:

- `AGGREGATE(9,6,C4:E4)` calculate sum of numerical values
- `COUNTIF(C4:E4,NA())` count cells with `#N/A` (as those worth `1` counting them is just fine)
- `COUNTIF(C4:E4,"<>")` count cells which are not empty

[image]